# Mongoose: updating document and returning a specific part of it

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm building a simple chat app. My problem is that when I update conversation model by adding a message to messages array I somehow need to return this message along with its `_id` & `createdAt` fields (which are generated automatically). Is it possible to do so using mongoose?

I can achieve this by doing the following:

```
const { messages } = conversation;
const lastMessage = messages[messages.length - 1];
```

My piece of code that updates a model looks like this

```
conversation.messages.push({
  conversationId,
  sender: _id,
  body,
});

conversation.save((err, conversation) => {
  if (!err) {
    const { messages } = conversation;
    const message = messages[messages.length - 1];

    pubsub.publish('messageCreated', {
      messageCreated: message,
    });

    return message;
  }
});
```

I'm curious whether `mongoose` has such functionality built in, or I need to leave everything as it is. I'm not sure if my current solution is effective and will work fine if a `messages` array has thousands of messages

Answer (score 1):

Use `update` operation:

```
conversation.update({
    $push: {
        messages: message,
    },
}, (err) => {
    // ...
});
```

It will be more efficient in such case. But if you have a lot of read/write operations over one conversation or need to select some part of messages array then you should to move messages to separated collection.

Comment: A separate collection? Won't it affect performance? Because in this case a `messages` collection will contain tens of thousands of messages from ALL the conversations & searching for messages will take more time

Comment: It will be more efficient then transferring huge objects via db connection. MongoDB is fast and can manipulate big amounts of data. Proper indexing will help DB. Also you can create collection for each conversation, but I don't think it will be necessary for you.